# Angular inconsistently updating class attribute when browser tab is blurred

Tags: css, angularjs, browser, websocket, focus

I have an angular app with a view that connects and subscribes to a websocket to receive remote updates.  On receipt of a 'change_phase' message the new value (a string) is applied to the model, and that string set as a CSS class on a HTML node in my template (to allow me to highlight the current state of 'phase').

This all works perfectly well while I am looking at the app in the browser, but when I turn my back something terrible happens.  If I trigger multiple changes on the server while a different tab is focussed, then go back to the tab with my app then the CSS attribute does not update correctly, although the textual representation of the phase value does.

An example of the behaviour...  If the view is loaded and has the phase set to 'C', and I trigger server changes of phase to 'A', then 'B', then 'C' and I go back to the browser tab then both 'B' and 'C' are highlighted.  If I output the value of 'phase' in the template it is 'C', but the class attribute says both B and C are applied.

Here is the view template:

```
<div>
    <span>Phase :::: {{s.phase}}</span>
    <div class="phase-buttons" ng-class="s.phase">
        <button ng-click="updatePhase('A')" >PHASE A</button>
        <button ng-click="updatePhase('B')" >PHASE B</button>
        <button ng-click="updatePhase('C')" >PHASE C</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the update method called on receipt of the websocket message:

```
function phaseReceived(newPhase){
    $scope.s.phase = newPhase;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen or what I can do about it?  As I said - if the current tab in the browser is my app - then it all works perfectly, even if there are other windows with focus. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this problem occurring in multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes - same result in both Chrome and Firefox on Fedora and Windows.